# Server side is not working after react app build being deployed and served locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, web-deployment

I am using create-react-app and I am encountering some problem with react build. I am not integrating the client and server-side together as this can be troublesome for client-side routing.

The problem:
I have started with deploying my react build with heroku, git, netlify, firebase. And yes, I can see the exact page as I was doing with `npm start`. However, I can't fetch data from the server, it gives me a strange response from the server: `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` Even though the status code is `200`, I did not receive any data as expected.

[image: Text]

Also, console.log shows this error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`
[image: Text]

I suspect that the problem comes from the connection of javascript folder to the `index.html` because I see this line of code in my `index.html`:

```html
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

1. I did not turned off javascript and I have already make sure that it is turned on.
2. I have successfully deployed my server folder with Heroku and it works well with my local client(`npm start`), but it doesn't work with the `built` folder
3. It works normally if I use `npm start` to run the server, it must be something wrong in my `built` folder. I did not modify the path of the `build` after running `npm run build`, the `testing-create-react-app` is my client folder:

[image: Text]

So I have decided to create another create-react-app to check whether it produces the same error. I follow the guideline from the create-react-app documentation:

```js
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

but I still encounter the same problem. So here I will show my code here:

```
1. App.js
2. server.js
3. package.json
```

```js
// 1. App.js

function App() {

  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

  // fetching data from server
  useEffect( () => {

      fetch('/tester')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setMessage(data.message))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])


  
  return (
    <div className="App">

        <h1>why my build is not working</h1>
        {
          message
          ?
          message
          :
          <h1>no message</h1>
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// 2. server.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// express middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/tester", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "lol"
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

// handle error
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
    console.log(`Logged Error: ${err}` )
    server.close(() => process.exit(1))
})
```

```js
// 3. package.json
{
  "name": "testing-create-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit ***

My `server.js` is located at:

[image: Text]

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/p424l?file=/api/server.js

Appreciate if someone can help me with this

Comment: Where did you put the `server.js` file?

Comment: hi Dominik, I have edited my post and updated the location of the `server.js` file

Comment: So you added the `server.js` outside of the CRA folder. How do you run the node script? What command are you using? Fetching `/tester` means you have to run it on the very same server and port which means you need a proxy in-front of it... I'm not familiar with CRAs proxy options and assume your declaring it in the `package.json` file make that work. [more about that](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: I'm asking because the responds you're getting back suggests that this is hitting the CRA `/` root which is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: In this simple example, I just run it with `node server.js` and it is running on port 5000 but for the real project I declare `"server": "nodemon server.js"` in the server-side `package.json` file and run it with `npm run server`.  I have already declared proxy in my client-side `package.json` and it works without using the `build` folder.

Comment: I attach the sandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p424l?file=/api/server.js

Comment: There is no `server` script declared in your `package.json` neither in here nor in your codesandbox? Do you see the message `Server running on port ` anywhere? I suspect your server script isn't running

Comment: okay, I just used `npm init` to get a `package.json`. Now it should be working fine with `npm run start` in the`api` folder.